# R: Subsetting in overloaded [[ and [[<-

Tags: r, overloading, subset

If we have a list, we can subset nested values using `[[` directly or using a vector.

```
my_list <- list("main" = list(
  "a" =
    list("aa" = list(
      "aaa" = list("aaaa" = 0),
      "aaA" = 10
    ),
    "AA" = 20),
  "b" = list("bb" = list(), "BB" = list(10))
))

my_list1 <- my_list

my_list1[["main"]][["a"]][["aa"]][["aaa"]][["aaaa"]] <- 145

my_list1[[c("main", "a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa")]] <- 2222
```

Now we have closure with overloaded `[[` and `[[<-.my_class`:

```
dcon <- function(){

  data <- list()

  return(structure(function(named_list = NULL){
    force(named_list)
    if(!is.null(named_list)){
      for (na in names(named_list)){
        data[[na]] <<- named_list[[na]]
      }
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return(data)
    }
  }, 
  class = "my_class"))
}

`[[.my_class` <- function(dcon, name){

  return(.subset2(dcon(), name))
}

`[[<-.my_class` <- function(dcon, name, value){

  input <- list()
  input[[name]] <- value
  dcon(input)

  return(dcon)

}

my_list2 <- dcon()

my_list2(my_list)

my_list2[["main"]][["a"]][["aa"]][["aaa"]][["aaaa"]] <- 2222
```

The modified lists seem to be the same.

```
identical(my_list2(), my_list1) # TRUE

my_list2[["main"]][["b"]][["bb"]][["bbb"]] <- list(878)

identical(my_list2()[["main"]][["a"]], my_list1[["main"]][["a"]]) # TRUE
```

The question - how it is possible that this part:

`data[[na]] <<- named_list[[na]]`

works, while something like this (what to my understanding is equivalent of above):

`my_list1[["main"]] <- list("a" = list("aa" = list("aaa" = list("aaaa" = 2222))))`

does something different? `my_list1[["main"]]` behaviour is what I expect.

Why does it behave differently in overloaded parts?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following exactly what your question is. What exactly do you mean by "works" and "does something different"? What exactly is the behavior you expect? What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @MrFlick I've been trying to understand why this works. I've just noticed that value of `value` argument passed to `[[<-.my_class <- function(dcon, name, value)` is already modified nested list - in used example execution of `my_list2[["main"]][["a"]][["aa"]][["aaa"]][["aaaa"]]` causes that mentioned `value` is already modified: `list(a = list(aa = list(aaa = list(aaaa = 2222), aaA = 10), AA = 20), b = list(bb = list(),BB = list(10)))`. So where this reassignment happens if not in overloaded function? I am not sure if this explains my doubts clearly.